# Making a table dynamic according to the size of the screen in SWT

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, form-layout

I am working on Java SWT. I have created a table in Eclipse in the properties section. I have given a specific size to the table.

But I want the table size to be dynamic i.e if I have a larger screen then the table should adjust to the size of the screen. I am stuck here as I am a newbie to java SWT.

I have used FormLayout.

Comment: Which layout manager are you using?

Comment: I am using FormLayout